# Possible to move VM with a dedicated drive to a bare metal server?

Tags: virtual-machines, proxmox

I have several VMs running on Proxmox, each with a dedicated SSD. I need to move each one to it's own bare metal server. Would it be as simple as removing the drive and placing it in the new server, or would it be necessary to make a snapshot of the drive?

Edit: VMs are running Ubuntu server.

Comment: It depends what storage option you use for vm: raw device, some filesystem, qcow files or what. Also os may doesnt boot on real hardware without drivers or due configuration saved in registry for windows os

Comment: OS is ubuntu server, will edit this info in.

Comment: How they are stored on disks? What is a question https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/chapter-pvesm.html

Comment: I'm using drive passthrough. The drives are mounted to the host machine, let's say under /dev/sdb. I then installed the os on /dev/sdb1. I followed [this](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Passthrough_Physical_Disk_to_Virtual_Machine_(VM)) procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Only because you did a direct attach of a disk to a guest can this work without a restore from backup. Other Proxmox storage options are contained in volumes or files that are not physical disks.

The wiki page you linked to cites a typical complication:

> Note that device names like `/dev/sdc` should never be used, as this
> can change between reboots. Use the stable `/dev/disk/by-id` paths
> instead.

Use a stable name to update fstab and mount the disk in its new physical server. As the guest, now physical, is also Linux, many names for disks can appear in by-id. File system label or UUID, logical volume name if using LVM, LUN name or disk serials, partition UUID.

If this is disk is now the root device, may need to update boot loader. Modern grub can find itself via UUID, and boot a Linux root fs by any of these names. Try regenerating the grub config.